# How to use jQuery Validation plugin on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to execute a jQuery Validation plugin but getting a little issue. On the same button I have to first perform validation, and when the validation successful it execute some other jQuery code by getting the id of this button. for example view the code below.

```
    $(function () {

                $("#form-insert").validate({
                    rules: {
                        tbRollNo: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        tbRollNo: "Required Field"
                    }

                });

     $("#insertstd").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    debugger
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/Home/student',
                        data: {
                            Insert: true,
                            RollNo: $('#tbRollNo').val(),
                            Title: $('#tbTitle').val(),
                        },
                        success: function () {
                        },

                        error: function () {
                            alert("Oh noes");
                        }
                    });
 });
```

The button code is following:-

```
 <input id="insertstd" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

So when I click the above button it directly read the `$("#insertstd").click` function but does not start validation, and when I remove the `id="insertstd"` from button then it perform validation.

So I want that it should first perform validation and then run `$("#insertstd").click` function.

Comment: Please be more mindful when tagging your questions.  The jQuery Validation Engine is not the same plugin as jQuery Validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote Title:**

> *"How to use jQuery Validation plugin on button click"*

**Answer**:  You don't need to do anything because the button's `click` event is already captured automatically by the plugin and then validation is triggered.

In other words, the solution is to remove your entire `click` handler function and put the `ajax()` inside of [the `submitHandler` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) of the `.validate()` method.

As per documentation:

> `submitHandler`:  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. ***The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated***.

```
$(function () {

    $("#form-insert").validate({
        rules: {
            tbRollNo: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            tbRollNo: "Required Field"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // your ajax would go here.
            $.ajax({
                // your ajax options
                ....
            });
            return false; // extra insurance preventing the default form action
        }
    });

});
```

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"So when I click the above button it directly read the `$("#insertstd").click` function but does not start validation, and when I remove the `id="insertstd"` from button then it perform validation."*

That's because your `click` handler is interfering with the `submit` handler already built into the plugin.  When you remove the `id` from the button, you stop using your `click` handler and allow the plugin to validate.  Since you want to use `ajax()` *after* the form passes validation, you would put it inside the `submitHandler` callback option that is provided by the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes its working now but i face another little problem that is, when i write  e.preventDefault(); under submitHandler: function(form)...., its giving 404 page not found error. How can i avoid this error and use e.preventDefault(), thanks

Comment: @user3004110, why do you think you need preventDefault there?   That's not appropriate in this context.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question again because i am new to jquery. Actually i am trying to prevent page to refresh so that is why i used e.preventDefault(). And can you please little explain that why it is not necessary where i wrote it, thanks and appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3004110, You don't need it because if you simply follow my code, there would be no page refresh.  `.preventDefault()` has absolutely no business within the `submitHandler` and if you put it there, you're probably breaking something.  The plugin automatically handles everything and as long as you're including the `submitHandler` option, there will be no default form submit (no page refresh).  Therefore you must manually put form submission code inside of the `submitHandler`... in your case, `ajax()`.